# React day picker errors

Tags: react-native

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { globalStyles } from "../styles/global";
import {Calendar, CalendarList, Agenda} from 'react-native-calendars';
import {LocaleConfig} from 'react-native-calendars';
import  moment  from  "moment";
import DateRangePicker from "react-native-daterange-picker";
import DayPicker, { DateUtils } from 'react-day-picker';


export default function About(props = {}){

   const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState([]);

    function handleDayClick(day, {selected} ) {

        if (selected) {
          const selectedIndex = selectedDays.findIndex(selectedDay =>
            DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
          );
          selectedDays.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
        } else {
          selectedDays.push(day);
        }
        setSelectedDays( selectedDays );
      }

    return(

        <View style={globalStyles.container}>
             <DayPicker
              selectedDays={ selectedDays}
              onDayClick={handleDayClick}
            />


        </View>
    )
}
```

[image: error]

I have installed

npm install react-day-picker --save

npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev

I followed all steps mentioned in https://react-day-picker.js.org/
but getting this syntax error...
I have no idea about this error.. please help

Answer (score 0):

This is because the library is for React.js for web. This library does not support React Native. You need to find some library for react native